# Workout plan for fitness-studio

Tags: gym, running-training-plan

I recently started to visit a gym 2-3 times a week, because, as a programmer, I need some movement. Additionally, I have very low blood pressure which causes me nearly to faint sometimes when doing simple body-weight exercises.

I'm male, 19 y/o, 192cm, 85kg

Can you recommend a weight loss and condition gaining plan?

Currently; I'm about 90-120 mins in the studio:

- 20 min warmup on the bike (ca. 250 kcal)
- Row 2000m (ca 120 kcal)
- 3 x 25 crunches (25kg)
- 3 x 25 biceps curl (33kg)
- 3 x 25 triceps press (17kg)
- 3 x 25 shoulder press (25kg)
- 3 x 25 pull downs (29kg)
- some leg stuff (can't remember the names)
- 30 min on empty devices
- 10 min final on bike (ca 110 kcal)

Is there anything I could optimize?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Programs**

There are programs already made for you. Examples:

- http://stronglifts.com/5x5/
- http://startingstrength.com/

**Your current program**

As for the program you're doing right now, it's no good, I'm afraid.

There's nothing wrong with the exercises, but the fact that you do the same amount of reps, same amount of sets, same amount of weight every time. Your muscles need to be challenged, and if you just do the same thing over and over, you're not getting any stronger.

**Metaphor**

Solve these math problems.

2 + 2 = __

2 + 2 = __

2 + 2 = __

2 + 2 = __

Did you get any better at math? No, right? Because you've done this before, and there is **no progress**.

**Your caveats**

I don't know what's causing your low BP, and I'll assume that it's your doctor that recommended exercise. Even so, I'm not sure 1.5-2 hours in the gym is needed. If you get the compound exercises in (which it looks like you're already doing, and the programs I gave you would incorporate them too), you're gonna have progress.

Comment: I'd also add doing 20 minutes of warm-up is overkill. 5 to 10 minutes on an exercise bike (good for lower body workouts) or on a rowing machine (good for full body workouts) at a moderate pace suffices. And I'd stay closer to the 5 minute mark than 10. If he wants extra cardio, it's better to do it after the strength work.